# Floating container does not shrink when content does

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox, resize

I have a container in which I might add or remove elements (using javascript)

```
<div style='float:left;'>
    <p id='myp1'>elem 1</p>
    <p id='myp2'>elem 2</p>
    <p id='myp3'>elem 3</p>
    <p id='myp4'>elem 4</p>
    <p id='myp5'>elem 5</p>
</div>
```

Whatever I'll do, either **add** an element or make it **bigger** (with padding/margin/line-height and such) it will resize to fit.

Whatever I'll do, either **remove** an element or make it **smaller** (with padding/margin/line-height and such) it does not shrink.

It lefts me with more and more unused space.

This occurs in firefox only (as I noticed) and wrapping sub-content in other divs/spans/tables and such won't help me the problem still occurs.

(you can notice this bug by adding a border to your containing div)

It might be a normal behaviour that I just dont understand but to me it's just puzzling right now.

So thanks in advance for any advice or explanation at least !

Comment: Hey, maybe you could create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) case so we can take a full look and do some testing.

Comment: I did not know this, this seems awesome ! Thanks for this discovery !

Comment: Yep, it works for you, I'll try to track down the flaws in my design and come up with something more explanatory ...

Answer (score 0):

You can make the height auto of the container. so whenever your inner content will be added or removed your container height will automatically adjusted.